# Generate CSS background colour from a primary key that is drastically different from the next primary key

Tags: python, css

In Python I'm generating a 6 digit hex from the primary key of a model (in Django) that I can use as the CSS background colour for a div on a page.

If I have two primary keys which are close together how can I generate noticeably different colours. For example using the primary keys 24 and 25 give almost the same colour of black.

```
>>>format(24, "06X")
000018
```

and

```
>>>format(25, "06X")
000019
```

It would be good if I could get as different colours as red and green as the primary key increments.

Comment: why can't you just iterate over a fixed set? e.g `thiscss= colors[id % len(colors)]`

Answer (score 0):

It would be best not to generate colors from keys at all.
But if you want to/need to, you can outline the number to 24 bits. Then reverse the number. The lowest bits now become the highest.

This way, increment of 1 is always noticable, although numbers that are a bit further apart may still be very much the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
import md5, struct

def pseudorandom_color_from_int(value):
  return md5.md5(struct.pack('i', value)).hexdigest()[:6]
```

Example use:

```
>>> print map(pseudorandom_color_from_int, (24, 25, 26))
['503533', '2b197a', 'ed69df']
```

The colors appear to be random, but they are deterministic, so the same color will always result from a particular integer value.

Comment: But it's still possible that two respective keys will result in (almost) the same color. Though chances are small.